# Admob without overlaying the Android Game

Tags: android, admob

I know this should be easy but I am still learning and I am unsure how to get the AdMob banner to display at the top (stretched in width to fill the screen) without overlaying the game. This is written without any XML files and below is the code the I have that just displays the ad at the top of the screen overlaying the game.

Thank you guys in advance for any help you can provide.

```
public class Screen extends Activity implements Runnable, OnTouchListener, SensorEventListener {
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private boolean locker = true, initialised = false;
private Thread thread;
//public WakeLock WL;
private int width = 0, height = 0;
public float cameraX = 0, cameraY = 0;

public Activity activity = this;
public boolean debug_mode = false;
private long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), lastRefresh, lastfps;
public SurfaceView surface;
private int fps = 0, frames = 0, runtime = 0, drawtime = 0;

//sensor
SensorManager sm;
Sensor s;
float sensorx, calibratex = 0;
float sensory, calibratey = 0;
private boolean default_lanscape = false;
private int default_lanscape_rotation = 0;

//world origin
public final int TOP_LEFT = 0, BOTTOM_LEFT = 1;
public int origin = TOP_LEFT;

//layout
public RelativeLayout layout;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;

    //full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    //create surface
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    surface = new SurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(layout);
    layout.addView(surface);

    AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXX");
    //layout
    layout.addView(ad);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest(); 
    adRequest.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    ad.loadAd(request);

    holder = surface.getHolder();

    //listeners
    surface.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // start game loop
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

    onCreate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read about and understand how Android layouts or you aren't going to understand any help that is offered. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Having said that, start by replacing the RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout. And I strongly recommend you use an XML layout. You are far less likely to get lost especially since you are new to this.